# Code for calculating number of variations

Tags: c++, algorithm, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

Following up from my [previous](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/139259/calculating-number-of-variations) question where I put up a solution in brute for algorithm to [this](https://www.codechef.com/ZCOPRAC/problems/ZCO15002) problem from codechef.

> Given some number \$K\$ and a list of \$N\$ numbers, count the number of pairs (\$i\$, \$j\$) such that \$1 \le i \lt j \le N\$ and \$|a_i − a_j | \ge K\$.
>
> - \$1 \le N \le 65000\$
> - \$1 \le K \le 10^8\$
> - \$0 \le a_i \le 10^8\$

I changed my code quite a bit and was able to get rid of that `time-limit-exceded` error.Thanks to the responses, here is the updated code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>


std::vector<int>loadTestCases(int N){
    std::vector<int> testCases;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        int TestCase;
        std::cin >> TestCase;
        testCases.push_back(TestCase);
    }
    return testCases;
}

int main(){

    int args,k;
    std::cin >> args >> k;

    std::vector<int> nums = loadTestCases(args);
    int cases = 0;

    sort(nums.begin(),nums.end());


    for(int i=1;i<args;i++){
        int temp = std::abs(nums.at(i)-nums.at(i-1));
        if(temp >=k){
            cases = cases + i;
        }else{
            int j = i;
            while(temp < k && j > 0){
                j--;
                temp = std::abs(nums.at(i)-nums.at(j));
            }
            if(temp >= k){
                cases = cases + j + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << cases << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But according to me the code still looks a little ugly and can be optimized more , can someone help me to identify the parts where simplification without risking the time taken can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to the other question, I would suggest to utilize a std::map changing your loadTestCases accordingly

```
std::map<int, int>loadTestCases(int N){
    std::map<int, int> testCases;
    int TestCase;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> TestCase;
        auto inserted = testCases.emplace(TestCase, 1);
        if(!inserted.second) {
            testCases.at(TestCase)++;
        }
    }
    return testCases;
}
```

The advantage of this approach is, that you only have to traverse the keys of the std::map once and can multiply the values if there is a match.

Also given that your container is sorted you can actually skip the std::abs call, as a_i - a_j > 0 is guaranteed by that sort, if you traverse the container from the back. Also more importantly, once you find a_i - a_l > k, you automatically know, that any following pair is also valid, as by construction for an a_m < a_l we get a_i - a_m = a_i - a_l - (a_m - a_l), with (a_m - a_l) < 0.

Comment: Note that starting from front is equivalent of a_i-a_j < 0

Answer (score 1):

Optimize on **design level**, not **source level**. Your program performs the following:

1. Read input
2. Sort
3. Find pairs

The respective complexities are \$O(n)\$, \$O(n~log~n)\$ and \$O(n^2)\$ in your implementation. For now, we can ignore 1. and 2. and focus on finding pairs of distance \$\geq K\$ in a sorted set.

A sorted set has a couple of nice properties:

- You must only search for the first element with a sufficient distance to base. You already use that information.
- \$j > i\$. You already use this property too.
- When you find a pair \$(i_1,j_1)\$ and search for another pair \$(i_2,j_2)\$ with \$i_2 \geq i_1\$, \$j_2 \geq j_1\$ must also hold true.

You can base your inner loop on \$j_1\$ instead of \$i_2\$, which eliminates it altogether, making the search \$O(n)\$. The result are two pointers that traverse the set in a single pass. The pointers keep a distance of \$K\$

- If \$d < K\$, the leading pointer advances.
- If \$d \geq K\$, the trailing pointer advances.

and are therefore guaranteed to hit every pair of interest exactly once.

```
int countPairs(const std::vector<int> sortedNums, int k)
{
    const size_t size = sortedNums.size();
    size_t trailingIndex = 0;
    size_t leadingIndex = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while (leadingIndex < size)
    {
        if (sortedNums[leadingIndex] - sortedNums[trailingIndex] < k)
        {
            leadingIndex++;
        }
        else
        {
            count += size - leadingIndex;
            trailingIndex++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Execution time is reduced by an order of magnitude and well within the required limit.

```
int main(){
    int args,k;
    std::cin >> args >> k;

    std::vector<int> nums = loadTestCases(args);
    sort(nums.begin(),nums.end());

    int cases = countPairs(nums, k);

    printf("%i\n",cases);
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to improve it any further, you must focus on the sorting algorithm which became the limiting factor (\$O(n~log~n)\$ vs. \$O(n)\$). You may consider using an [Integer Sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_sorting) algorithm instead of the generic comparison sort.

Comment: Personally i would not use a while loop if I know the exact range of the loop.  EDIT: Sorry, missread the condition.